# Why must casting to a derived class be explicit rather than implicit

Tags: java, object, casting, implicit

`Object o = new Student(); // Implicit casting`

I understand this code very well , and what I understand is that reference variable "o" refer to data of "Object" type and as we can see Student is extending from "Object" which means that it refers to an instance of Student.
and if I wrote the following code :

`Object x = o;`

This will assign the value in o into x , which means if we followed the direction of x we will go to that student object above !

My question here is , why can't I write the following code? :

```
Student x = o;
```

"o" refers to an object of " Object " type and that object assigns it's address ( in memory ) into "o" , why can't we assign that value saved in o into x !

Comment: This could make for very difficult bugs, and cryptic code.  Also the compiler couldn't easily handle this feature. This is obviously possible, so I'd chalk it up to a great design decision.

Comment: Because the designers of Java did not choose to replicate Visual Basic. It's a matter of their taste.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Object o = new Student();  //upcasting - Implicit cast
Student x = (Student) o;   //downcasting -Explicit cast
```

**Upcasting**: We're narrowing the reference conversion (moving up the inheritance hierarchy). Since a Student `IS-A` Object, it does not require an explicit cast

**Downcasting**: We're are widening the reference conversion (moving down the inheritance hierarchy). Since Object could be anything, we must use an explicit cast to cast it to a Student.

Answer (score 5):

There is no casting going on here.

As you say, `Object` is a base class of `Student`.
This means that every instance of `Student` is also an `Object`, and we can always treat it as one.

```
Object o = new Student(); // A Student is an Object
```

The opposite relation does not hold, however - not all instances of `Object` are `Student`s.

After you have assigned the `Student` to `o`, the information that it's *actually* a `Student` is unavailable to the compiler.
That information is available at runtime - you can say `o instanceof Student` and it will 
be true - but the compiler does not know that.

Answer (score 3):

```
Object o;

if (Math.random < 0.5) {
  o = new Student();
} else {
  o = new Dog();
}
```

You can't have `Student x = o;` obviously

Unless the dog is also a student, but that's a different story.

Answer (score 2):

Java only allows implicit upcasting, not implicit downcasting.

Upcasting in Java is also called widening conversion, and downcasting is called narrowing conversion.

Objects can be implicitly or explicitly cast to a supertype. In this example, `Object` is a supertype of `Student`.

```
Object o = new Student();
Object x = o; // implicit works
Object x = (Object) o; // explicit works
```

Objects cannot be implicitly cast to a subtype, and must be explicitly cast. In this example, `Student` is a subtype of `Object`.

```
Object o = new Student();
// Student x = o; // implicit doesn't work
Student x = (Student) o; // explicit works
```

[Explicit and Implicit Type Casting - Herong Yang](http://www.herongyang.com/Java/Reference-Type-Explicit-and-Implicit-Type-Casting.html)

[5.1.5. Widening Reference Conversion - Java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.5)

[5.1.6. Narrowing Reference Conversion - Java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.6)

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly cast this to Student

```
Student x = (Student) o;
```

The reason for this is because the compiler doesn't know if this is correct, so you need to cast this as if to say **"I am confident that this will work. Please trust me"**.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign the instance of Student to a variable declared to be of type Object, because every Student is a kind of (or specialization of) Object. Since not every object IS A Student, the compiler balks at the assignment of something it knows only to be an instance of Object to any specialization of Object, such as Student. So, you can assign to an instance variable of a more general type implicitly without difficulty, but in the opposite direction the compiler wants some assurance that you mean to do this, so you explicitly downcast.

```
Student x = (Student)o;
```

This is simply the nature of a statically typed language.

Answer (score 1):

You basically have to see if it passes the `IS-A` test, you can say `Student IS-A Object` (as every class in Java is a subclass of class Object) which is why the first implicit cast works.

However you cannot say an `Object IS-A Student` because it might not be. Unless you know for a fact that it will be a `Student` then you can do a *downcast* with:

```
Student x = (Student) o;
```

Just in case you make a mistake with that *downcast* though, you might want to wrap it in an if statement like so:

```
if(o instanceof Student) {
    Student x = (Student) o;
}
```